# Errno 13 Permission denied: '/home/ubuntu/Demo/website/media/image_banner/download.jpg'

Tags: django, apache2

I built a Web site using the Django framework, one of which was to process images uploaded by the admin and save them in a folder for media/image_banner, but encountered an error ([Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ubuntu/Demo/website/media/image_banner/download.jpg'. I use python manage.py runserver and it works, but it doesn't work when deployed with Apache2.

this is  port 80 file code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/Demo/website

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
    Alias /static /home/ubuntu/Demo/website/static
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/Demo/website/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/Demo/website/website>
    <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
    </Files>
    </Directory>
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIDaemonProcess website python-path=/home/ubuntu/Demo/website python-home=/home/ubuntu/Demo/demo_env
    WSGIProcessGroup website
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/Demo/website/website/wsgi.py
```

Comment: you need to make that directory writable for other users, did you execute some commands using `sudo`?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused for the lackings of permission. You should give proper read-write permission **/home/ubuntu/Demo/website**

```
sudo chmod 777 /home/ubuntu/Demo/website -R
```

This command will give all the permission (read, write, execute) to the **website** directory including all directories and files inside the **website** directory. But for production, you need to change the permission for the security issue.

Comment: Another Error show:- AttributeError at /register/
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'is_ajax'

Comment: seems this error coming from your view. Do you use request.is_ajax or something like that?